# How to retrieve the currently searched for text in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

For example, I have some code and I use "*" to search for something within that code. Not finding what I want in that file, I'd like to use something like `ack` or `grep` to search for it within the local directory. I know I can do `:! ack whatever` to do the search from within vim, but what I'd like to know is is there a way to replace `whatever` with the currently searched for word within vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riffing off of [Tim Henigan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739135/how-to-retrieve-the-currently-searched-for-text-in-vim/2739223#2739223), put this in your .vimrc

```
cmap <C-R>/ <C-R>=substitute(substitute(@/, '^\\<', '', ''), '\\>$', '', '')
```

Now when you hit `CTRL-R /` in command line mode, it will drop the word boundry markers, so you should be able to use

```
:!grep CTRL-R / file-list
```

Comment: Awesome, this is just what I was looking for. I did modify your mapping a little bit to avoid having to hit the enter key twice:

`cmap <C-R>/ <C-R>=substitute(substitute(@/, '^\\<', '', ''), '\\>$', '', '') <CR>`

Comment: Another option is to use the `g*` search command rather than `*`.  See my updated answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739135/how-to-retrieve-the-currently-searched-for-text-in-vim/2739223#2739223

Comment: `ctrl-r` followed by `/` inserts the text from the search register, but if you were to do `ctrl-r` followed by any letter on the keyboard, it would insert the contents of the corresponding register. Besides the letters, there are other special registers, such as `.` (the last entered text), `%` (the current filename) etc. By remapping `ctrl-r` you lock away all of the potential useful shortcuts that can be constructed from these various registers.

Comment: @nelstrom: I'm not remapping `CTRL-R`, I'm remapping `CTRL-R /`.  All the other `CTRL-R` commands still work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Ctrl-r followed by / to insert the last-search register.

```
:!grep <Ctrl-r> / file_list
```

See this [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Substitute_last_search) entry for more info.

**Update:**
The `*` search command command always includes word boundaries.

However, the `g*` search command behaves the same as `*`, but without word boundaries.

This could be used to work around your issue rather than using the custom macro in [rampion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739135/how-to-retrieve-the-currently-searched-for-text-in-vim/2739679#2739679).

Comment: This works, although when used in conjunction with `*` it also has the word boundaries. Is there anyway to get the text without them?

Comment: The `*` search sets up the search pattern to include the word boundaries.  So you can't use `*` to get the pattern without them.

Comment: @Paul Wicks: See my update regarding the `g*` search command.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to (easily) pass the contents of a search register to an external program, without resorting to key mappings and eval statmements.

However, you can use `<cword>` to pass the word currently under the cursor to an external program:

```
:!echo <cword>
```

or

```
:!ack <cword>
```

Comment: I do exactly that (`:! echo @/`), but the output of echo is literally '@/'.

Comment: Anyway to get the text, without the word boundaries?

Comment: @Tim Henigan, my mistake, `:echo @/` will show you the contents of the `/` register...

Answer (score 0):

You can yank the word into a register and use the @regnum in the command mode line

"1yw
:!grep @1